# ¿Como programar una interfaz que actualizce los archivos y version de mi sistema?

Tags: powerbuilder

Tengo un sistema completo de ventas hecho en power builder, el cual a aun presenta ciertos fallos, lo tengo instalado en diferentes empresas, todas con conexion a internet, quiero hacer que se ejecute una vez al dia una instruccion, que, antes de abrir el sistema, al cerrarlo o en un boton que diga "Actualizar version", me permita verificar en un servidor si hay alguna nueva actualizacion de mi sistema, cambios, y que se descarguen y actualicen todos los archivos de mi sistema.
Si se puede hacer en Power Builder seria ideal, y si no, pues tambien puede ser en otro lenguaje como c, o java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías dar mas información sobre donde planeas poner los archivos de la nueva versión? 
Podes hacer lo siguiente:

Creas un script que se va a ejecutar en vez del programa verdadero(le llamaremos actualizador), este prgorama verificaría si hay una nueva versión y si es así, actualizaría los archivos y por último abriría la aplicación verdadera actualizada.

Para que todo el proceso sea transparente para los clientes, crearías un acceso directo al actualizador en vez de al programa verdadero y le pondrías el mismo icono(los accesos directos permiten poner cualquier icono sin importar el destino). Los usuarios piensan que están abriendo el programa verdadero pero en realidad están ejecutando el actualizador que al final del proceso abre el programa verdadero ya actualizado.

Si todos los clientes están en la misma red y podes crear una ruta de red que puedan ver todos los clientes como en mi caso, podes usar este script:

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

exe_file = "app_verdadera.exe"
fldr_org = "\\ruta_de_red\ActualizarSistema\"
fldr_dst = Left( Wscript.ScriptFullName , InStrRev( Wscript.ScriptFullName   , "\" ))

'Si el programa esta abierto no actualice
Set Process = GetObject ("WinMgmts:Root\Cimv2").ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = '" & exe_file & "'")
IF Process.count = 0 THEN 
    FOR EACH file IN fso.GetFolder(fldr_org).Files
        file_org = fldr_org & file.Name
        file_dst = fldr_dst & file.Name

        IF NOT fso.FileExists(file_dst) THEN
            'Si el archivo no existe, lo copio
            fso.CopyFile file_org, file_dst, true
        ELSE
            'Si existe, compara las fechas 
            date_org = fso.GetFile(file_org).DateLastModified
            date_dst = fso.GetFile(file_dst).DateLastModified
            'Si las fechas de modificacion son diferentes, actualizo
            IF DateDiff("s", date_org, date_dst) < 0 THEN
                fso.CopyFile file_org, file_dst, true
            END IF
        END IF
    NEXT
END IF  

'Ejecuto el verdadero programa
IF fso.FileExists(fldr_dst & exe_file) THEN
    shl.Run """" & fldr_dst & exe_file & """"
END IF
```